# What is the clause "still Plato's most frequently read work" referring to?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, sentence-meaning

> The *Timaeus* was seen as central to Plato’s metaphysical thinking until the 19th century, when obsession with Plato’s political thinking replaced it by the *Republic*, **still Plato’s most frequently read work.**

I'm having a little bit of trouble comprehending the clause here. Which book is "still Plato's most frequently read work" - is it *Timaeus*, or *Republic*? Do I have to supply "which is" before "still", as if the sentence were to be "... replaced it by the Republic, (which is) still Plato's most frequently read work"? In this sense I feel like it's *Republic*, but to me it's still a little bit vague and uncertain.

Is there any chance that the "most frequently read work" is referring to *Timaeus*? Like, the whole sentence is suggesting that "despite the fact that the political obsession replaced *Timaeus* by *Republic* (central work metaphysically), *Timaeus* is nevertheless still Plato's most read work".

Thanks!

Comment: I can't come up with any reading other then _The Republic_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Which book is "still Plato's most frequently read work"

It's *Republic*.

> Do I have to supply "which is" before "still"

You can.  It's not strictly required, but you can.

> Is there any chance that the "most frequently read work" is referring to Timaeus?

No.

Why? This looks like an adjective phrase being used in a [supplemental appositive](https://motsjustes.wordpress.com/2009/08/18/tuesday-afternoon-punctuation-commas-part-x%E2%80%94adjectival-phrases-and-appositives/) manner, so "X, still Y" would normally only modify X.

English has the verb "to be" to connect X and Y in a way so that we can provide more details Y on what defines or how X is differentiated; and you generally can always use it for maximum clarity.  However there are also a lot of grammatical constructs in English that "shortcut" and place X and Y next to each other to accomplish the same thing; including the very basic "adjective noun" structure.

> Take the red sock and put it in the laundry.

> Take the sock which is red and put it in the laundry.

Comment: Can you provide an example of "to be" in your last paragraph? Sorry but I don't quite get the meaning of "to be". How does it provide maximum clarity?

Comment: More words in a sentence makes things clearer, because it gives a listener more chances to pay attention.  The last sentence in my response "Take the sock which is (<-form of *to be*) and put it in the laundry" is the example.

Answer (score 1):

This test means that *Republic* is "still Plato’s most frequently read work." Work refres back to the most recent preceding noun which could plausibly fit, herE that is clearly "Republic". "which" is not required, but might increase the carity.

Answer (score 0):

The Timaeus was central to Plato’s metaphysical thinking **until** the 19th century. Then the Republic took over in popularity and it still remains his most frequently read work.